# Preventing an incorrect address being assigned when updating/inserting data into CMS system

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, database-design

I'm currently building part of a basic CMS system for the company I work for. There are three main tables...

Companies
Customers
Addresses

Which are all linked to together with foriegn keys. I've noticed a glitch when using SQL Server 2005 where if I add a new lead the address maybe updated between the selection of an existing address and the creation of a company causing the company to then have the wrong address associated with it.

My question is... how can I prevent this? Transactions? Timestamp on the address - whereby when the record is selected it gets updated and if the timestamp is different to what the update statement has it inserts a new record?

I'm trying to write a scaleable solution as this is part of the e-commerce website. Users can update their details and much as we can ourselves.

Help.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand. If a user chooses the correct address "123 Main St, Anytown, CA" for a new company, what is that address being updated *to*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to change the data model: adresses are not stand-alone entities that should be referenced, but simply part of the companies' data.

You could still use a separate table for the adresses, but each company will have its own specific rows in that table, never share the same rows with other companies.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It was one of the considerations I'd thought about as it wouldn't be too hard to implement. What I'm trying to achieve is minimising the duplication of address data with the possibility of a later date using the data as the seed to allow people to select an address.

Comment: I understand, but the fact is that an address is not an entity like a company or a person - if you modify the adress of a company from '9 Bridge Street' to '23 Coryell Avenue' you are not modifying 'the address', you are modifying 'the adress of the company XXX'. Keep a separate addresses table, but each time you edit an address create a new entry in the table, do not modify an existing entry - and periodically clean out the address rows that are no longer referenced.

Comment: So what you're suggesting, in a nutshell, is to add a reference to the address if it already exists or create a new one when adding an address. Then when someone updates an address it does the same. Then run a purge function on a daily or weekly basis for instance. I like that idea a lot! :-)